# Block numbers from being entered in an input field

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-6

Okay, first some background, I can't use any javascript library except YUI for this project.

What I'm trying to do is take an input and block it to only allow numeric input. I know this is easier to just do in validation, but the PM wants it onkeypress. What I have was constructed from running around the net and works great in firefox. Unfortunately, this has to be compatible with IE8 and IE6, and it works in neither.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onlyNumbers(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode        

        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

        return true;

    }
</script>
<input type="text" id="<%=Model.HtmlID %>" value="<%= startingAnswer %>"name="<%=Model.HtmlID %>"
 maxlength="<%=maximumLength %>" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event);" />
```

Any ideas on what is wrong with it that is making it not work in IE?

Comment: The majority of big sites have stopped IE 6 support, unless you're competitors are still supporting it I'd recommend doing everyone on the web a favor dropping support for it.

Comment: Yeah. Client is a very large company that is still using IE6, this is an internal module for them.

Comment: Please do the world a favor and don't break functionality when modifier keys are pressed. Check for `evt.shiftKey`, `evt.altKey`, `evt.ctrlKey` and `evt.metaKey`. I don't remember offhand if that's all cross-browser compatible, but if not it's likely that YUI fixes that sort of thing.

Comment: Hey, have you figured that out ? I need the same thing and I got into the same situation

Comment: @lisak Yes, I did. I'll post it on here as an answer in just a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onlyNumbers(target) {
        var newVal = document.getElementById(target).value;
        if (isNaN(newVal)) {
            document.getElementById(target).value = newVal.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
        }
    }


</script>
<input type="text" id="<%=Model.HtmlID %>" value="<%= startingAnswer %>"name="<%=Model.HtmlID %>"
 maxlength="<%=maximumLength %>" onkeyup="javascript:onlyNumbers('<%=Model.HtmlID %>');" />
```

It took some extra effort, and a little creativity, but I did get this one figured out. This doesn't really disallow the input, instead it simply wipes out anything that isn't allowed as soon as you let go of the key. Actually works on IE6 too

Comment: I suppose that this works for all browsers but it is very ugly solution, because the letters are displayed in the input field, even a lot of them if you don't release the up-button and it can be even submitted

Comment: @lisak: Yes, I agree. It's a hideous solution. I hate the fact that I had to write such a clumsy hack. But it was the only thing I could find (even having tried all the solutions I could find around on here) that would work universally between IE8, 6, and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

YUI has text field validation as part of its forms module.
An example (YUI 3)

```
var myForm = new Y.Form({
method : "post",
action : "/test.php?action=submit",
inlineValidation : true,
fields : [
    {name : 'input1', type : 'text', label : 'Numbers only: ', validator : 'IntegerField'},

    {type : 'submit', label : 'Submit'},
    {type : 'reset', label : 'Reset'}
]
});
myForm.render('#formContainer');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't part of a stand-alone form, it's a pretty freakish mash-up of ascx files all stuffed together in a modular fashion. Does this work, by any chance, outside of a YUI form?

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure. I think it handles the whole form for you from rendering to validation. Sorry! It looks like you got the proper workaround in place by your answer.

Comment: unfortunately, no...it still doesn't work in IE. It seemed like it did for a few minutes, but apparently I was wrong. Now I'm trying to find a way to do a running regex on the entire string in the text box onkeyup to rip out anything that isn't text...